# Pointers C Linkedlist Adding Always NULL

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I've written a function for adding to the end of a singly linked list in C.  But what I don't get is why if the head element is NULL, why it continues remaining to be NULL after successive adds.

The struct is defined as this:

```
typedef struct node* node;

struct node {
    int data;
    node next;
}
```

In the main I have this:

```
node test = NULL;
add(test,1);
add(test,2);
add(test,3);
```

function add is defined as such:

```
void add(node head, int newData) {
    node n = createNode(newData);
    if (head==NULL) {
        head = n;
        return;
    }
    else {
        node tmp = head;
        while (tmp->next != NULL) {
           tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        tmp = n;
    }
}
```

createNode is defined as thus:

```
node createNode(int data) {
    node n = (node) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    n->next = NULL;
    n->data = data;
    return n;
}
```

What I am confused about is that, the add function works fine if I first initialize the head (node test = createNode(1)) and then proceeds to add the rest of the values alright.  But if I leave the test node to be NULL, it doesn't add any values?  What is happening here?

Comment: pass `node*` to your function `add`, it will work. Also, u need to change the code in ur function accordingly .

Comment: @jpw; He is right. He should have pass pointer to pointer.

Comment: But for the function to work u need to pass a double pointer. Well, i will try to write a proper answer to this.

Comment: Hint: don't `typedef` pointers, but the struct. This will create less confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write function `add` the following way

```
void add( node *head, int newData ) 
{
    node n = createNode( newData );

    while ( *head ) head = &( *head )->next;

    *head = n;
}
```

or you can write even the following way

```
void add( node *head, int newData ) 
{
    while ( *head ) head = &( *head )->next;

    *head = createNode( newData );
}
```

and call it like

```
node test = NULL;

add( &test, 1 );
add( &test, 2 );
add( &test, 3 );
```

Take into account that function `createNode` must be declared before function `add` and you missed a semicolon in the structure definition

```
struct node {
    int data;
    node next;
}
^^^
```

Also it is not a good idea to use the same identifier for a struture tag and pointer to the same structure

```
typedef struct node* node;
```

At least it would be better to write something like

```
typedef struct node* node_ptr;
```

Comment: The issue is due to scope, so you are right, also I just found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25780563/linked-list-implementation-in-c  Thanks!

Comment: @roostersign Of course function createNode should be declared before function add.